# UISearchBar + UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm new to ios, but I couldn't find the answer anywhere. 
I got a UITableView showing products. In the HeaderView I got a UISearchBar. The idea is that with the SearchBar you can filter the rows in the TableView. I don't want to / can't use the "TableView" the SearchBar lays on top, so I hid it with `searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.hidden = YES;`. This works finde, the rows get filtered and the user can click on a desired element.

The Problem is that my TableView isn't scrollable anymore! How can I avoid this? I set `self.tableView.scrollEnabled = YES;` in searchBarTextDidBeginEditing.

visual demonstration: http://d.pr/i/vqiK

Thanks for your help.

How I added the SearchBar to the TableView:

```
searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, SEARCHBAR_WIDTH_EXPAND, SEARCHBAR_HEIGHT)];


searchDisplayController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:searchBar contentsController:self];

self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar;

searchBar.delegate = self;
```

Comment: Could you show how you add the header with searchbar to the table?

Comment: I've added the code to my question.

Comment: Well, so you need searchbar be scrollable with the table content?

Comment: No I just want the TableView scrollable. But as soon as the Search is active you can't scroll inside the TableView (only click on the rows you see)

Comment: When you say it isn't scrollable do you mean the tableView doesn't even bounce (if you move you're finger down does the rows move down and then bounce back up?)

Comment: If you don't want searchbar to be scrollable you'd better add it to the main view: `[self.view addSubview:searchBar];` instead of adding it as a header to the table. I think it'll help.

Comment: @Andrey If this is in a UITableViewController subclass, then self.view is the tableView.

Comment: @Jonathan as soon as the search is active no scrolling or bouncing is possible. Maybe the TableView from the SearchBar that I hidden is causing the problem?

Comment: @AndreyChevozerov The SearchBar is perfect, I want that the TableView can scroll again.

Comment: @D-32 I think the source of problem is in the search bar: when it is firstResponder, it blocks scrolling of table. If you'll move it out of table scrolling should work again.

Comment: What do you mean with moving out? I need it inside the TableView, because first it should be hidden, and only when the user scrolls up it should show.

Comment: Well, did some tests. When you set SearchDisplayController it makes great work with searching and displaying results, but it also locks the corresponding view. So if you want your table scrollable I think the only way is not using such controller and implement your own search logic.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, seems that if I don't use the SearchController it works, cool! Any idea how I could make the SearchBar stick to the top but only when search is active?

Comment: @D-32 There are two ways to add header to the table: via property and via appropriate delegate message. In the first case you'll have scrollable header which scrolls just like all other cells. In the second case you'll get floating header which scrolls only up to top and then stay here. But none of this ways is suitable for your task... So I don't know how to do that simple and elegant :)

Comment: Okay, but thanks anyway, you're a life-saver!